# Lack of extension when loading Firebase using systemJS

Tags: firebase, systemjs

I'm writing an Angular2 app which uses Firebase through AngularFire2 and I've run into trouble loading Firebase files. SystemJS bootstraps the app, loads `firebase.js`, but afterwards fails to load the files required in it, due to the lack of the extension. In particular, it sends a request to `http://localhost:8080/node_modules/firebase/app` instead of `http://localhost:8080/node_modules/firebase/app.js`. The latter exists in the bundle and is therefore definitely the right thing to load.

Here is my `system.config.js`:

```
(function(global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'aviary':                               'js',
    'rxjs':                                 'npm:rxjs',
    'firebase':                             'npm:firebase/firebase.js',
    'firebase/app':                         'npm:firebase/app.js',
    'angularfire2':                         'npm:angularfire2',
    '@angular':                             'npm:@angular'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'aviary':                       { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                         { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api':   { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angularfire2':                 { main: 'bundles/angularFire2.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},

};
var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
];

// Individual files (~300 requests):
function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}

// Bundled (~40 requests):
function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}

// Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

// Add package entries for angular packages
ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages,
    paths: {
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    }
};

System.defaultExtension = true;
System.config(config);

})(this);
```

One of the things I tried was

```
var packages = {
    //...
    'firebase':                     { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

but that did not help. It feels like it's a configuration issue, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make it do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `system.config.js`, package config for `firebase` does not apply because you mapped `firebase` to a file, and package config basically works only for directories. Mapping to files works only when the module really is just one file. When it needs to load other files from the same directory, you have to map the module to the directory and use `main` in package config, like this:

```
var map = {
    ...
    'firebase': 'npm:firebase',
}
```

and

```
var packages = {
     ...
    'firebase':  { main: 'firebase-browser.js' }
}
```

Notes:

1. it looks like you don't need separate mapping for `firebase/app`
2. with the latest version, the main file for firebase is `firebase-browser.js`, not just `firebase.js`
3. You don't need `defaultExtension: 'js'` in package config because `js` is already the default for any package.
4. I'm not sure what this line does, nothing changed when I removed it:

   ```
   System.defaultExtension = true;
   ```